# How to dispatch mouse wheel event in older IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I want to create and trigger/dispatch a mousewheel event in IE8 that I can track in a event handler.

In IE8 `document.createEvent == undefined`, so tried this but with no success:

```
var evt = document.createEventObject();
view.fireEvent('onMouseWheelEvent');
```

I would like to fire and listen mouse wheel events in IE7~9.

Any pointer would be helpfull, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It does look like you may be out of luck as far as IE8 support goes. I'm finding quite a bit of evidence ([Microsoft/Google](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/scroll.html), [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/wheel), [Facebook](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/631)) that IE8 implements the handling of the mouse wheel/scroll events in such a way that you can't work around them.

Comment: I'm finding the same. Trying to add the equivalent of the modern "wheel" event support to old browsers,  and IE8? I can attach an 'onmousewheel' event to an element and it will be called when the wheel is turned, though supposedly (according to MSN) it won't. But it doesn't matter because even after the event is triggered, the handler will have no way to detect which way the wheel has turned. So that's pretty useless.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the event object in arguments to fireEvent, not only the event type.

```
var evt = document.createEventObject();
view.fireEvent('onMouseWheelEvent', evt);
```

Check for the existence of document.createEvent `if(document.createEvent)` and execute either the above or

```
var evt = document.createEvent('MouseWheelEvent');
evt.initMouseWheelEvent( evt, true, true );
view.dispatchEvent( evt );
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453179.aspx for further parameters.

Comment: This thread is from 2014, and its 2020 as I write this.  But if you happen to see it, the 'onmousewheel' event does seem to trigger on IE 8. But none of the "delta" properties seem totally absent. Any way around that?

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me in IE 8 and FireFox:

```
var triggerButton = document.getElementById("triggerMouseWheel");

triggerButton.onclick = function() {
    if (document.createEvent) {

        var mouseEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
        mouseEvent.initMouseEvent(
            'DOMMouseScroll',
            true, true, window, 120, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null
        );
        document.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);

    } else if (document.createEventObject) {

        var mousewheelEvent = document.createEventObject(window.event);
        document.fireEvent("onmousewheel", mousewheelEvent);

    }
}
```

The second part using createEventObject is used in IE8 and below, I believe.

The code I used to add the event handler is below for reference too:

```
function addMouseWheelEvent(element, mouseWheelHandler) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
        element.addEventListener("mousewheel", mouseWheelHandler, false);
        // Firefox
        element.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", mouseWheelHandler, false);
    }
    // IE 6/7/8
    else element.attachEvent("onmousewheel", mouseWheelHandler);
}

addMouseWheelEvent(document, function() { alert("triggered"); });
```